# scheduling jobs on mac OSX 10.8.2

Tags: mac, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to schedule the execution of a `.sh` script on max OSX 10.8.2

I am using `crontab` and am getting an odd bug.  If i am at the computer and set the task so that it executes in the next few minutes, it starts up as desired, however if i set it for sleeping time (as i wish to), it does not run.

My `crontab` file looks like this:

```
1  6  *  *  *  /Users/me/bash/script.sh
```

Is there some setting i need to flip so that these tasks execute even when the computer has not been interacted with for a time (i presume it's hibernating or some such)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cron doesn't run when the computer is off or asleep. Use a [LaunchDaemon](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) instead, and use the `StartCalendarInterval` key to trigger it:

```
...
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/Users/me/bash/script.sh</string>
</array>
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<dict>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>6</integer>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
...
```

Comment: +1, thanks. This would be my first LaunchDaemon, could you possibly showmthe entire xml? Would be a massive help to me. Thanks.

Comment: I found this a bit tricky, so i made a tutorial on my [blog](http://ricardianambivalence.com/2013/03/13/scheduling-tasks-with-macs-launchd-moving-on-from-cron/)